# AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT OpenCL Cycles Render 2.91

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

this is my first time using an AMD card with Blender and I was wondering how I get it to work. When I switch the rendering device to GPU compute and to OpenCL, in blender 2.91, it just crashes. The CPU rending works fine but whenever I try to use the GPU for rendering Blender just stops responding. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: AMD cards have a long history of problems with blender...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=rx+5700

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for days with Radeon RX 580, today I updated the drivers to 20.12.1 (released in 2020. 12. 04.) and the problem is no more.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and see if it works.